# Is my bad code causing Paypal to show misleading generic "Message 3005"?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

When sending customers to Paypal from my website I am seeing a new error message I've never spotted before:

> Error Detected
>
> We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.
>
> Message 3005

Googling this message suggests it is just one shown to the general public when Paypal is overloaded....but I don't think that can apply to me becuase the Paypal site responds normally to other parts of my website which use a HTML link. It is when I use an ASP.NET `Response.Redirect` that I see the error.

I have checked the URL is correct and encoded correctly. So I really would like clarification that message 3005 is indeed one that can be shown when the incoming request is erroneous, as well as when the Paypal site is under heavy load.

Is this generic message shown in both circumstances? Is `Response.Redirect` acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Googling this message suggests it is just one shown to the general public when Paypal is overloaded..."
And that's why you can't always trust Google results.

No, a '3005 error' does not mean PayPal is 'overloaded'. It is a generic error which can be returned for various internal and external reasons.
It's the PayPal equivalent of '*Something* went wrong', without actually saying what went wrong.

Can you reproduce this error consistently? And if so, what are the steps to reproduce it?
Can you include your code?

Comment: Is there a page where Paypal actually state that message 3005 is shown in various circumstances? Searching their developer network only yeilds results in the 'forums' section, where other people have issues and get the message, but there is never any clear closure as to the message meaning!

Comment: There are no 'specific' causes as such; it varies on a case by case basis. In normal usage, you should never see it. If you do see it, I would suggest reporting it to PayPal via https://www.paypal.com/mts

Comment: Aha! Now I understand. Thank you for replying, I appreciate it. I will report it...although my code has mysteriously started working, and I'm now finding it hard to recreate the issue reliably.